# Cannot update/remove/reinstall postgresql 14

Tags: apt, package-management, 21.10, postgresql

On Ubuntu 21.10,

When trying to do anything with `apt` on package `postgresql` (`Ubuntu 14.4-1.pgdg21.10+1`), the process hangs on the `Setting up postgresql-14 [...]` line :

```bash
$ sudo apt remove postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postgresql
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 71,7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 574023 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postgresql (14+241.pgdg21.10+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-14 (14.4-1.pgdg21.10+1) ...
```

Same with `apt remove`, `apt reinstall`, `apt upgrade`...

Can I force the removal without this initialization step ?

edit: `dpkg` says that the package is not installed :

```bash
$ sudo dpkg -i postgresql
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'postgresql': No such file or directory
```

however, `apt autoremove` still hangs :

```bash
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postgresql-14 (14.4-1.pgdg21.10+1) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a script called `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-14.postinst`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -e

VERSION=${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE##*-}

if [ "$1" = configure ]; then
    . /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions

    configure_version $VERSION "$2"
fi
```

that was the apparent cause. By commenting the content of this script, the problem disappeared and I finally could unblock `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Firstly

If you haven't updated your system in a while, you would, first, need to run:

```
sudo apt update
```

an up to date package database is equally needed for installs as well as removals of packages.

#### Secondly

The issue you are having:

> `Removing postgresql (14+241.pgdg21.10+1) ...`
>
> and then
>
> `Setting up postgresql-14 (14.4-1.pgdg21.10+1) ...`

i.e. the system tries to install a package after trying to remove it when you specify `apt remove package-name` ... usually, indicates that the package is in a broken/unstable state ... either it was not properly installed in the first place (missing/corrupted files) or you changed some of that package's installed files i.e (names, permissions, paths or contents) ... you'll need to fix it first ... the easiest way to fix a package is to reinstall it like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall package-name
```

or to forcefully reconfigure(**use caution with `--force`**) it like so:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force package-name
```

Then, read this excerpt from [man apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html):

> **Removing** a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small
> (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the remove was an
> accident. Just issuing an installation request for the accidentally
> removed package will restore its function as before in that case. On
> the other hand you can get rid of these leftovers by calling **purge**
> even on already removed packages. Note that this does not affect any
> data or configuration stored in your home directory.

and decide whether to use:

```
sudo apt remove package-name
```

or:

```
sudo apt purge package-name
```

or (**caution required**):

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq package-name
```

To understand, read this excerpt from [man dpkg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html):

> A  package  marked  reinst-required  is  broken  and requires
> reinstallation. These packages cannot be removed, unless forced with
> option **--force-remove-reinstreq**.

or as a last resort(**extreme caution required**):

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all package-name
```

#### Finally

Carefully, read the error messages and pay attention to exact package naming ... for example `postgresql-14` is generally **not** the same as `postgresql`.

Comment: All `apt` commands hang on this line (including `purge`, and `install --reinstall`).